# How to access a method without using class object in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

Suppose ClassA has method1(); in main method We want to access method1() without creating object of ClassA.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a class method you can call it like below:

```
use ClassA;
ClassA->method1();
```

---

Example:

**ClassA.pm**

```
package ClassA;

sub welcome_message{
    my $class = shift;
    my $name = shift;
    print "Hello $name";
}

1;
```

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use ClassA;
my $name = 'John Doe';
ClassA->welcome_message($name);
```

Please go through [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).

Comment: It might want to do something with `$self` (or `$class`), like call another method. It would be better to use the `->` syntax and say `ClassA->method1` instead.

Comment: A couple of suggestions. Firstly, I only use `$self` in object methods. For class methods I'd use `$class` as the name of the variable storing the invocant. Secondly, I like to get the invocant with `shift` before processing any other parameters (`my $self = shift`). This has two advantages - firstly it shows that the first argument is special in some way and secondly, it leaves `@_` containing the actual arguments that the user passed to the method. YMMV :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two types of method. The most common type is an object method - a method which is called on an object (i.e. an instance of a class). In the vast majority of cases, calling an object method without an object is going to be completely pointless as it will need to either read data from the object or write data back to the object.

However, there are also class methods - methods that are called on classes. The object constructor (usually called `new()`) is probably the best-known example of a class method. You call a class method using the class name, the arrow operator and the method's name.

```
Some::Class->some_method;
```

You can also pass parameters to the method.

```
Some::Class->some_method($some, $parameters);
```

This is all rather vague, but without knowing a lot more about what you're doing and why you want to call a method without and object, it's impossible to be any more help.

**Update:** I've just realised that this was my 1000th answer on SO :-)